# How to fill area above the intersection of matplotlib graphs matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to select an area at the intersection of two graphs?
So I need something like this:
[image: What I need]

What I have:

```
x1 = np.arange(0, 20, 0.01)  
f1 = x1 * 0 + 5/3
f3 = -0.25 * (-x1 + 7)
plt.plot(x1, f1, 'm', linewidth = 3,  label='f1', alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(x1, f3, 'y', linewidth = 3,  label='f3', alpha = 0.5)
plt.fill_between(x1, f1, f3, color='r', alpha=0.1, label='Area')
```

[image: My attempt]

I was able to select the area only between. Is it even possible to do this with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area above two curves is defined by taking the maximum at each x-position:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(0, 20, 0.01)
f1 = x1 * 0 + 5 / 3
f3 = -0.25 * (-x1 + 7)
plt.plot(x1, f1, 'm', linewidth=3, label='f1', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(x1, f3, 'y', linewidth=3, label='f3', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(x1, f1, f3, color='r', alpha=0.1, label='Area between')
maxf1f3 = np.max([f1, f3], axis=0)
plt.fill_between(x1, maxf1f3, maxf1f3.max(), color='b', alpha=0.1, label='Area above')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: filling area above two curves]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx), passing `where`:

```py
plt.fill_betweenx(f3, x1, where=f3>=f1 , color='r', alpha=0.1, label='Area')
```

Comment: This probably only works when f1 is a constant horizontal line. In other cases it will color a parallelogram between `x=0` and the line `x1,f3` stopping at the point where `f1` and `f3` cross.